# store rows retrieved from database as separate variables in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a loop which displays the wanted rows but I also want each row to be stored in its own variable in php. I have a table that has an ID and an info column.

This displays the wanted ID and info:

```
if ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()) { 
do {
echo "$info[id] . $info[info] </br> "; 
   } while ($info = $stmnt2->fetch());
} else {
echo "<p>No Info</p>";
}
```

I want each row to have its own variable so I can manipulate the data later down the line. Like the first row will be stored in a php variable called $one and the second row in $second.
 How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just store the data in an array then refer to the array positions? Depending on your record count you could intentionally have over 100+ variables...

Comment: Differently named variables like $one, $two, etc is a really bad idea; why not have an array instead?

Comment: @thenoob Do you want do edit the values in PHP or in your browser later on?

Comment: Question's a bit unclear; seems like you're trying to query from two different queries and/or different tables; given `$stmnt` and `$stmnt2` suggests it.

Comment: @Sebastian in PHP

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry $stmnt should be $stmnt2

Comment: @thenoob I tend to think that you'd want to do something like `$var1 = $info['id'];` and inside the `while` loop. I don't know you're doing a `do/while`, rather than just a simple `while`.There is currently nothing in your `while` loop. See the manual on PDO's `fetch()` also http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php - You may have to do a `foreach`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for your help, down the line I want to be able to update a row based on the selected row ID. Like display the rows and have an edit button which takes in the parameter of the row ID so I can update that row. That is why I think I need variables which store the row ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a variable to solve this! Take an array instead:

```
$rows = [];

if ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()) { 
    do {
        $rows[] = $info;
        echo $info['id'].$info['info']."</br>"; 
    } while ($info = $stmnt2->fetch());
} else {
    echo "<p>No Info</p>";
}

if (!empty($rows)) {

    //you can change the values of the rows like the following.
    $rows[0]['id'] = 1; // The ID of the first row!
    $rows[0]['info'] = 'Some Info'; // The info of the first row!
    $rows[1]['id'] = 2; // The ID of the second row!
    $rows[1]['info'] = 'Some Info'; // The info of the second row!
    //...
}
```

With the above example each item on `rows` is one row (`$rows[number_of_row - 1]`).

> **Hint:** `$info[id]` and `$info[info]` isn't valid. You have to replace these with `$info['id']` and `$info['info']`!

Comment: It's `rowNumber - 1` to be precise :)

Comment: I made an arror $stmnt is $stmnt2 sorry

Comment: I get a  Fatal error: Cannot use []. for rows[] = $info;

Comment: my bad. `$rows[]` instead of `rows[]`!

Comment: row indices start from 0, not 1, which is why it's rowNumber - 1

Comment: how would I store the actual ID from the database which is in $info['id']

Comment: What do you mean by `store the actual ID from database`? On `$rows[0]['id']` is the ID of the first row. On `$rows[1]['id']` is the ID of the second row...

Comment: Sorry, I removed = 1 etc thought it was part of the code and now it is working thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just add `$info` to an Array:

```
if ($info = $stmnt->fetch()) {
  $array = [];
  do {
    echo "$info[id] . $info[info] </br> ";
    $array[] = $info;
  } while ($info = $stmnt2->fetch());
} else {
  echo "<p>No Info</p>";
}

// Do stuff with all rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','yourdb');

if($resultobj=$mysqli->query("select * from yourtable limit 4")){
   list($one,$two,$three,$four)=$resultobj->fetch_all();
}
print_r($one);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($info = $stmnt2->fetch()) { 
$array=[];
do {
$array[$info['id']][]=$info; //the array index will be the same as id from the db
echo "$info[id] . $info[info] </br> "; 
   } while ($info = $stmnt2->fetch());
} else {
echo "<p>No Info</p>";
}
```

The array index will be same as the id in the DB.
To Retrieve the content use

```
$array[1]['info'] //will retrieve content id id = 1
```